# How to Inject spring JDBCTemplate to Jersey Resource classes ( Which Consumes XML and produces JSON ) using Annotations?

Tags: jersey, spring-jdbc

I have develped some **REST services** in my present application using **JERSEY framework**.
In this application, I am posting  **RequestXML** to the JERSEY and getting **JSON** Response as a output.

**web.xml**

```
<servlet-name>VVCServices</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.vzw.vvc.resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VVCServices</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/customer/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

**CustomerLookUp.java**

```
@Path("/getCustInfo")
public class CustomerLookUp {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomerLookUp.class);

    @POST
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })

    public Response getCustomerInfo(VVC  vvc) throws Exception {

        logger.info("getCustomerInfo - ENTRY");

        String format="XML";
        Response response = null;
        com.vzw.vvc.customer.VVC.Response response1=new com.vzw.vvc.customer.VVC.Response();
        VVC.Response.CustomerInfo cusInfo =  new VVC.Response.CustomerInfo();    

          cusInfo.setEnrolled(true);
          cusInfo.setEnrolledDate(Utils.getXMLGregorianCalendarNow());
          cusInfo.setAccountNumber("23454");
          cusInfo.setDeviceId(new Long("56566"));
          cusInfo.setPlanId(new Long("4574963"));
          cusInfo.setBalancePastDue(true);
          response1.setCustomerInfo(cusInfo);
          vvc.setResponse(response1);

        ByteArrayOutputStream xml = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(VVC.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        //output pretty printed
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(vvc,xml);
        response = Utils.getResponse(xml,format);
        logger.info("getCustomerInfo - Exit");
        return response;
    }
}
```

**Utils.java**

```
public class Utils {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Utils.class);

    public static Response getResponse(ByteArrayOutputStream xmlResponse, String format) {

        Response response = null;
        JSONObject jsonObject;          

        logger.info(" in utils.java -- Entry");
        try {
            jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xmlResponse.toString());

            if (format.equalsIgnoreCase("JSON")) {
                response = Response.ok(jsonObject.toString(),
                        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
            } else {
                response = Response.ok(xmlResponse.toString(),
                        MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).build();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
}

    public static  XMLGregorianCalendar getXMLGregorianCalendarNow() 
            throws DatatypeConfigurationException
    {
        logger.info("IN getXMLGregorianCalendar()- Entry");
        GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        DatatypeFactory datatypeFactory = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
        XMLGregorianCalendar now = 
            datatypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregorianCalendar);
        logger.info("XMLGregorianCalendar:"+now) ;
        return now;
    }
}
```

**customerInfoPost.jsp** For posting RequestXML and MIME type ..etc threw JQUERY attributes.

```
<input type="button" value="CustomerLookUpService" onClick="btnClick()"></input></br>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var btnClick = function () {

            var reqXml = '<VVC><ServiceHeader><ServiceName>CustomerLookup</ServiceName><Operation>testing</Operation><ClientId>11333</ClientId><UserInfo><UserId>9933</UserId><UserClass>sampletestingclass</UserClass></UserInfo></ServiceHeader><Request><SearchCondition><CustomerId>2147483647</CustomerId></SearchCondition></Request></VVC>';

            var url = 'http://localhost:8080/VerizonVirtualCareServices/customer/getCustInfo';

            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: url,
                contentType: 'application/xml',
                cache: false,
                data: reqXml,
                dataType: "xml",

                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 

                    onCompleted(data) 
                    },

                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    onCompleted(textStatus); 
                    }
            });
        }
```

**By hitting the above Service ,this is the JSON:**

```
{"VVC":{"ServiceHeader":{"Operation":"testing","ServiceName":"manusample","UserInfo":{"UserClass":"sampletestingclass","UserId":"9933"},"ClientId":"11333"},"Response":{"CustomerInfo":{"DeviceId":"56566","BalancePastDue":"true","PlanId":"4574963","Enrolled":"true","AccountNumber":"23454","EnrolledDate":"2014-03-20T19:06:28.739+05:30"}},"Request":{"SearchCondition":{"CustomerId":"2147483647"}}}}
```

At that time, for the sake of **POC(proof of concept)** I was supposed to put the **hardcoded** data rather contacing the **DB** (oracle) and getting Actual Data.

Now I would like to know how to use **Spring jdbc** in Jersey Rest service for DataBase intraction.

I hope to respond on this article any one feel free to share.

**English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors**

Thanks

**Madhava**

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring and Jersey together.  Then your resource classes (CustomerLookup in your case) can be initialized as a bean with scope "prototype" and you can inject your JdbcTemplate normally.  How to do it depends on your version of Jersey.  I'm on Jersey 1.8 and this is how I would do it.

Given your example, change the servlet in web.xml thusly:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>VVCServices</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.vzw.vvc.resources</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

If you're using Spring annotations, add your annotations to your class declaration:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@Path("/getCustInfo")
public class CustomerLookUp {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomerLookUp.class);

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate

    @POST
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Response getCustomerInfo(VVC  vvc) throws Exception {
        ... rest of your code ...
    }
}
```

Of course, there are many ways to initialize Spring beans so I don't know if that fits with your current method, but that's what I do in my application and it works well.

If you are using Jersey 2.x, there is an example available here: https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.7/examples/helloworld-spring-webapp